# Convert a generic type constructor to non generic type constructor

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

For example, I have class

```
class TestClass<T>
{
}
```

I have some method that receives the constructor of this class.
I want to invoke that constructor with some generic parameter without calling MakeGenericType and GetConstructor method again.

```
static void Main()
{
    var ctor = typeof (TestClass<>).GetConstructors().First();
    Invoke(ctor );
}

static void Invoke(ConstructorInfo ctor)
{
    //ctor.Invoke() - it will not work because TestClass has a generic parameter.
    // I want something like ctor.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int)).Invoke();
}
```

Is it possible somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: `var result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int)));` or if you want to find out `ConstructorInfo`: `typeof(TestClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int)).GetConstructors()...`

Comment: You must provide `T`. You have to call it like `typeof(TestClass<int>).GetConstructors()`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(ctor.MethodHandle, typeof(TestClass<int>).TypeHandle);
```